# CSS selector ignore nested children

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a nested set of list where I need to select only the first node of children and ignore anything below it.

```
<ul class="parent">
    <li class="node">
        <a>A link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="node">
        <a>A link</a>
        <ul class="sub-child">
            <li class="node">
                <a>A link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="node">
        <a>A link</a>
    </li>
<ul>
```

In this case I want to style the links `<a>` but only ones directly under `parent`>`node`. What does the selector for this look like in CSS?
I tried `.parent .node a` but that will also apply to the link under `sub-child`>`node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` means directly under the element

```css
.parent>.node>a {
  background: red;
}

.parent>.node>.sub-child>li>a {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="node">
    <a>A link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="node">
    <a>A link</a>
    <ul class="sub-child">
      <li class="node">
        <a>A link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="node">
    <a>A link</a>
  </li>
  <ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know what was a thing in CSS

Answer (score 2):

I think this will give you what you are looking for:

```
.parent > .node > a
```

Not *any* `.node` below `.parent` node but only the **direct** child `.node` of `.parent` node. And not *any* `a` child  of `.node` but only **direct** `a` child of above `.node` node (who is a direct child of `.parent` node).